# CKEditor unable to override styles on non-span tags?

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to use CKEditor to edit some html created with a different tool (Quill) that has a different opinion on which tags one should place style attributes.
For example:

```
<p>
  <strong style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0);">TEST</strong>
</p>
```

When one tries to use CKEditor (standalone V4.6) to change the color of this line of text one gets the following (which doesn't work due to the new color being overridden by the old color)

```
<p>
  <span style="color:#00ffff;">
    <strong style="color: rgb(230, 0, 0);">TEST</strong>
  </span>
</p>
```

It seems obvious that any inner tags should get their color style removed when the color is set but I have been unable to find a way to configure CKEditor to do that.  It seems like a bug that it doesn't.  Is there any way to get CKEditor to do this?  (this applies to all style properties, not just color)

If not, is there a way to get CKEditor to normalize the html on load so that all styles are extracted out to spans?

Comment: What are using ckeditor with... Drupal, standalone, what version etc..

Comment: Please mention what is this other tool you speak of?